# is there a plugin in jenkins to limit characters input for a string parameter?

Tags: jenkins, cloudbees

I am using a String parameter for my jenkins job. Parameter shouldn't allow more than 11 characters when a user inputs during build. Does Jenkins have a plugin that can do this?

My workaround: By default, I am trimming that string to 11 char and using it in the code.

Comment: What would you benefit from such a plugin if you can solve it that simply?

Comment: I highly doubt there is such an plugin but I would have suggested you to use your workaround.

Comment: My use case: Users provide a parameter during Jenkins build and validate same value in AWS after job completion. If the value is trimmed, their manual validations are failing. So, I wanted to see if there is a plugin that supports my usecase.